# Past participle of verbs that end in r - When do you add an extra r?

Tags: spelling, past-participles

Examples:

> lower - lowered
>   transfer - transferred

How can you distinguish between such cases?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The basic rule is that the r is doubled if the vowel before it is stressed in the past participle.

Other examples:

> answer/answered
>   labor/labored
>   offer/offered
>
> bar/barred
>   star/starred
>   confer/conferred